# How to merge in changes from a git branch that contains submodules when the working branch doesn't use submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Lets say there is a large repository that contains multiple submodules, and the main developers have decided that submodules shouldn't have been used, thus they removed the submodules and began tracking all the files within one repo.

Now imagine that some other developers checked out the code *before* the submodules were removed and made some useful changes. What is the best way to merge these changes into the main branch (which now tracks *all* files instead of using submodules)?

Is there anyway to do so beyond telling the developers working on the old branch that they need to patch their version so that the submodules aren't used, prior to merging?

Comment: *Best* is always tricky, but note that changes made to submodule repositories are commits made to different repositories (since that's all a submodule is, really: a separate repository that you normally keep on a detached HEAD). They have no bearing whatsoever on commits made in the superproject. So you have to figure out how to take "snapshots that improve repo S" (the submodule) and turn them into "commits that improve repo M" (the main superproject). That's usually a matter of turning snapshots into diffs (format-patch), then applying the diffs.

Comment: Note that there's no need to keep submodule commits out of the main repository.  It's often enough more convenient to carry them there.  That would make the pre-merge "patching" and any needed grafts very, very easy.

Comment: Thanks @torek, I will look into that

Comment: @jthill do you mean that I should bring in the commits from the **old** submodules into the main repo? I know this is doable, but seems a bit messy. With that said, submodules are always messy business...

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Your other devs are going to splice the submodule histories into their main histories, having them in a single repo makes referring to them easier and faster.